# References citation

Tags: bibliographies

My references, while cited appear like this, especially ref 4.

[image]

I need the format to be like

Ramachandran, P., Rajan C. S., and Ramakrishnan. M (2003).

Please let me know how to get this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! please show us in a short, compilable code how you build this bibliography. Do not forget to add the bib entrys to your question!

Comment: The whole sample format is provided here. https://github.com/The-WebOps-Club/iitm-thesis-template

Comment: Hello, sending an external link leading to multiple files is not really polite for the people trying to help. In any case, you could have a look at [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management) as a starting point.

Comment: The link you showed does not use `biblatex`, it uses `natbib`. So I have retagged your question. You can make it much easier for us to help you by providing a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and not just a link to a multitude of files.